# What is the best way to rotate several buttons in a jpanel around a central point?

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

I am working on a project in which I have a background image with specific points of interest. Each of these specific points will have a custom button class overlaid on it so that when I click the point, I'm actually clicking the button. However, I would like to be able to rotate the background image and have the buttons rotate with the image so that the custom buttons are still overlaid on the specific points. Any tips as to how I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually wanting to rotate 4 different images and move them around the square, but always keeping them upright? Or are you rotating a single image so that after one button click the single image is on its side?  If the former, then that can be easily done by using a container (a JPanel) that uses BorderLayout, and having four JPanels with background images and JButtons held in the container JPanel at the four compass points of the BorderLayout: BorderLayout.EAST, BorderLayout.WEST, BorderLayout.NORTH, and BorderLayout.SOUTH (although Java gurus prefer you use the newer constants, i.e., BorderLayout.PAGE_START). Then when a button is pressed, remove components and re-add but in a rotated order.

If you want to do the latter, then things get a bit trickier in that you'll likely need to use AffineTransforms, rotate instance to rotate the container, and you'll need to perform the same transformation on the point of the mouse press/click/release, so that the rotated buttons receive correct clicks.  If the container is not square, things get even trickier still.

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided more details. I would like to be able to rotate the image in degrees (using a slider) and have the buttons follow along with the rotation, but not remain upright. What I'm working on is making a simple map program in which I have a static background image and then I will be placing the buttons (small circles) over the areas of interest. When I rotate the map (the image), I would like the buttons to stay true to their designated areas on the map.